# Gatsby-browser recognizing only one export and ignoring the rest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, gatsby

I am trying to use multiple functions in `gatsby-browser.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import Wrapper from './src/templates/pages-layout'


export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => <Wrapper>{element}</Wrapper>

export const onRenderBody = (
  { setHeadComponents, setHtmlAttributes, setBodyAttributes },
  pluginOptions
) => {
  console.log('onRenderBody')
  ...
}

export const onPreRenderHTML = ({ getHeadComponents, replaceHeadComponents }) => {
  console.log('onPreRenderHTML')
  ...
}
```

Only `wrapRootElement` works, the other two are ignored and the console.log is never called.

Answer (score 1):

Move server side functions `onRenderBody` and `onPreRenderHTML` to `gatsby-ssr.js`
(I'm not sure if you'll see the output in the browser or in the node console)

Comment: I tried that too and deployed the code, however it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Gatsby's documentation about browser API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/api-files-gatsby-browser/) it's highly recommended to replicate the same configuration between `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js`, especially when using `wrapPageElement` or `wrapRootElement`. This is because the pages generated through SSR with Node.js are the same after being hydrated with browser JavaScript.

In addition, there's no `onPreRenderHTML` or `onRenderBody` method in the documentation for Gatsby Browser API. They are [Gatsby SSR](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/ssr-apis/#onPreRenderHTML) methods, and due to this, the `console.log` is shown in the running terminal, not in the browser console since the code is executed by the server. The only shared methods are `wrapPageElement` and `wrapRootElement` this is why usage needs to be cloned in both files. Your code wasn't ignoring anything, the methods are simply undefined in the `gatsby-browser.js` file and shown in the terminal console in the `gatsby-ssr.js` file.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did.

Comment: `onPreRenderHTML ` and `onRenderBody` are SSR API methods, so, the `console.log`  will be never shown since the code is executed in the server (you may find the log in the terminal, not in the browser). Your code is not ignoring the `console.logs`, they are simply undefined in the `gatsby-browser.js` file and shown in the terminal in the `gatsby-ssr.js` file. The only shared methods are `wrapPageElement ` and `wrapRootElement `.

Comment: Thanx, but regardless, the actual code in the gatsby-ssr file doesn't work, not only the console log. This is what I am trying to implement https://marcelhauri.ch/how-to-render-helmet-meta-tags-before-styles-in-gatsby/